# Why Bootstrap navbar is showing badly in IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple page with fixed navbar, but it is showin badly in IE.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

but in FireFox it looks:

[image]
I thaught Bootstrap problems should be solved by this:

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

in my header.

Here is my html:

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
      <a class="brand" href="./index.html">link</a>    
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
<div class="subnav subnav-fixed">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="careers.html">CAREERS</a></li>
   <li><a href="contacts.html">CONTACTS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How would I solve this ? If you need css I will add it.

Comment: How does http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ look in IE? Is it working there?

Comment: @Rich Bradshaw, yes, it is looking ok, but a little bit square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link an additional stylesheet in the IE if statetement that has the specific code below. You might need to sacrifice some parts of the navbar, such as the gradients (I don't think IE8 supports those).

```
ul.nav {
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    font-size: 12px;
}
ul.nav li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
ul.nav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
ul.nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kBdu4/)**